# How can I draw a tree like this?

Tags: support, mathjax, images

I want to draw the following tree in a question. But, I don't want to upload a picture. Can anyone tell me how to do it using MathJax?[image: The Tree]

Comment: Why don't you want to upload a picutre? I don't believe it's possible to replicate this with MathJax...

Comment: See [How could I add a graph to a post at MSE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/how-could-i-add-a-graph-to-a-post-at-mse) and some other questions on meta tagged ([meta-tag:images]).

Comment: As far as I know, diagonal lines are not possible with any graph-drawing environment (namely `amscd`) available for use on the website.

Comment: It would be nice if TikZ were supported by MathJax, but it's not. Uploading a picture may be your only option.

Comment: Som older questions related to TikZ: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/using-tikz-on-math-stackexchange and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/graphs-in-questions-tikz

Comment: Hmm... Seems like it's the only way. Sad. Anyways, thank you for the input.

Comment: You can find an image of (probably) that tree in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1170277/159634) of mine. Feel free to use it if you wish/need.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It **can** be done in MathJax, but it is painful and a complete hack.  Here is one way:

```
\require{enclose}
\def\uline#1#2{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\phantom{\Rule{#1em}{#2em}{0em}}}}
\def\dline#1#2{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{\phantom{\Rule{#1em}{#2em}{0em}}}}
%
\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1em}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}
%
\hskip 1em
%
\place{0}{12}{\bullet}
\place{2}{0}{\bullet}
\place{4}{4}{\bullet}
\place{6}{0}{\bullet}
\place{8}{8}{\bullet}
\place{10}{0}{\bullet}
\place{12}{4}{\bullet}
\place{14}{0}{\bullet}
\place{16}{12}{\bullet}
%
\place{.3}{4.4}{\dline{3.6}{7.6}}
\place{2.3}{.5}{\uline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{4.3}{.4}{\dline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{4.3}{4.4}{\uline{3.6}{3.7}}
\place{8.3}{4.4}{\dline{3.6}{3.6}}
\place{10.3}{.5}{\uline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{12.3}{.4}{\dline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{12.2}{4.4}{\uline{3.7}{7.6}}
%
\place{-1}{12.5}{\frac01}
\place{1}{-.5}{\frac13}
\place{2.75}{4}{\frac12}
\place{6.5}{-.5}{\frac23}
\place{7.75}{9.5}{\frac11}
\place{9}{-.5}{\frac32}
\place{12.75}{4}{\frac21}
\place{14.5}{-.5}{\frac31}
\place{16.5}{12.5}{\frac10}
%
\hskip18em\Rule{0em}{14em}{1.5em}
```

which produces

$$
\require{enclose}
\def\uline#1#2{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\phantom{\Rule{#1em}{#2em}{0em}}}}
\def\dline#1#2{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{\phantom{\Rule{#1em}{#2em}{0em}}}}
%
\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1em}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}
%
\hskip 1em
%
\place{0}{12}{\bullet}
\place{2}{0}{\bullet}
\place{4}{4}{\bullet}
\place{6}{0}{\bullet}
\place{8}{8}{\bullet}
\place{10}{0}{\bullet}
\place{12}{4}{\bullet}
\place{14}{0}{\bullet}
\place{16}{12}{\bullet}
%
\place{.3}{4.4}{\dline{3.6}{7.6}}
\place{2.3}{.5}{\uline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{4.3}{.4}{\dline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{4.3}{4.4}{\uline{3.6}{3.7}}
\place{8.3}{4.4}{\dline{3.6}{3.6}}
\place{10.3}{.5}{\uline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{12.3}{.4}{\dline{1.6}{3.6}}
\place{12.2}{4.4}{\uline{3.7}{7.6}}
%
\place{-1}{12.5}{\frac01}
\place{1}{-.5}{\frac13}
\place{2.75}{4}{\frac12}
\place{6.5}{-.5}{\frac23}
\place{7.75}{9.5}{\frac11}
\place{9}{-.5}{\frac32}
\place{12.75}{4}{\frac21}
\place{14.5}{-.5}{\frac31}
\place{16.5}{12.5}{\frac10}
%
\hskip18em\Rule{0em}{14em}{1.5em}
$$

It allows you to define an abstract grid on which you place the items you want (bullets for dots, fractions, and diagonal lines created using the `enclose` package).  I also use `\hskip` and `\Rule` to define the size of the complete diagram, and an `\hskip` at the front to compensate for the use of `-1` for the left-most labels.

Anyway, you can make these kinds of diagrams with some effort.

Comment: I'd like to mention this doesn't work on the iOS app

Comment: The numbers after place, for example \place{2}{0} are *relative* coordinates with respect to previous position? Or are they *absolute* coordinates?

Comment: @shieldbug1 And I can confirm that it does not render correctly on the mobile version of the site, using iOS's Safari (but switching to the "full site" in Safari still, it *does* work). Very interesting answer, either way!

Comment: @MartinSleziak, they are absolute with respect to the lower left-hand corner of the graph.

Comment: Thx for this great hack. $+1$  The diagram flooted on the code out of the screen though.

Comment: [Here's what it looks like on an Android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bzRQ.jpg); *viz.*, a ZTE Blade V8.

Comment: [Here's what it looks like on the same phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGNTF.jpg) but using the desktop site.